# using DCT to prove Uniform Integrable

Tags: probability-theory, uniform-integrability

If X$_n$ is dominated by some Y in L$^1$ or if it is identically distributed with finite mean, then prove that X$_n$ is uniformly integrable.

Approach:

Start with dominated convergence theorem but then how to use the fact of identically distributed with finite mean  and move towards X$_n$ being uniformly integrable.

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix $K>0$ and note that if $|X_n|\leq Y$ then
$$
E|X_n|I(|X_n|\geq K)\leq EYI(|X_n|\geq K)
$$
for all $n$, whence
$$
\sup_{n}E|X_n|I(|X_n|\geq K)\leq EYI(|X_n|\geq K)\to 0
$$
as $K\to \infty$ as desired.

The case of i.i.d with finite mean follows from the equality
$$
E|X_n|I(|X_n|\geq K)= E|X_1|I(|X_1|\geq K)
$$
and similar reasoning as above.